# The mystery FUNCTION PROTOYPE

Tags: c, function

I am studying about Information Technoloy at HCMUS. Through 3 years, I never see that prototype of this function.

```
static void
FUNCTION(fft_halfcomplex,pass_4) (const BASE in[],
                                  const size_t istride,
                                  BASE out[],
                                  const size_t ostride,
                                  const size_t product,
                                  const size_t n,
                                  const TYPE(gsl_complex) twiddle1[],
                                  const TYPE(gsl_complex) twiddle2[],
                                  const TYPE(gsl_complex) twiddle3[])
```

Could You explain what the central part of this prototype (`FUNCTION(fft_halfcomplex,pass_4)`) is to me?
I am sure that this code can run well. If you do not belive me, you can download this at http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/download_sources.html and you will see.
Thanks,

Comment: Search for the `#define` of `FUNCTION`…

Comment: I'd give `grep` a whirl and see that that `#define`s to. The same for `TYPE`, by the way.

Comment: There are actually two separate questions. 1 *what* happens here after pre-processing and 2 *why* it is done like that. For 1 run the compiler with the relevant command switch (typically `-E`), for 2 find the corresponding macros and read their code/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

FUNCTION() is a function-like macro, which will be expanded by the preprocessor to something like fft_halfcomplex_pass_4, depending on some defines.